# Is there a module for showing only posts in some defined date?

Tags: datetime

I would like to make a calendar addon for my website, which would look something similiar to http://www.nikerigarun.lv/ this (scroll it a bit downwards, on the right side). The funcionality would be to show only posts from some selected date, is there such a module for that and if there is, could you please recommend me one?

Answer (score 1):

This is done with the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module. Create a new view of content with a display type of 'block', and set it up as an unformatted list of teasers with links, then click 'Continue and edit'.

Add a filter on Content:Posted Day, and choose your conditions like 'is greater than' 'offset' '-10 days'.

You can then set any other views parameters to get what you want.

Save your view and go to **admin/structure/block** to find your block and place it where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

There exists a project (named [Calendar](http://drupal.org/project/calendar)) that contains a module that will do this for you with far less work than [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) alone.  Note that its functionality os based upon both [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) and [Date](http://drupal.org/project/date), so you need to have those projects installed as well.

The calender module will allow you to set up a graphic calender (like the one you link to), rather than just a list of future events.